# HiveQL: Remove leading spaces from string column

Tags: sql, regex, hadoop, hiveql

I have a table that looks something like this.

```
ID | Salary| Name|
_________________________
 1 | 50000|  Lee

 2 | 60000|  Camile

 3 | 70000|  Luther
```

Each name has a space in front of it; if I wanted to remove that space from all entries how would I do so? I've tried using regexp_replace but I can't get the syntax right.

So far I have come up with this but I don't know to how get it to work.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Emp(id string, salary int, name string)

ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':'

STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION '/user/xxx/employee/'

TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='3');

AS SELECT name, REGEXP_REPLACE(name, ' ')

FROM emp;
```

Comment: You might want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to ask great questions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ltrim` function remove all the trailing spaces from the string.

```
select id, salary, ltrim(name) as name from your_table;
```

Similarly the `rtrim` function removes all the leading spaces from the string.

```
select id, salary, rtrim(name) as name from your_table;
```

And the `trim` function removes all leading and trailing whitespace

```
select id, salary, trim(name) as name from your_table;
```

Comment: Sorry, I just edited it to update that I am creating a table while trying to remove the space. Could you take a look at my code?

Comment: What is your source table?

Comment: my hive doesn't seem to support trim

Comment: Well I'm trying to create a table that looks something like that; this is just a way for me to simplify things. The actual source table is going to be a giant table with way more entries. As of now I'm trying to run the regexp_replace function on table creation.